What causes the Econreset error with OpenAI libraries?
I have an app using html and the OpenAI Whisper model. Everything works as intended, However I keep getting an error when it tries to fetch the text output from the OpenAI servers.
I started the web page on localhost:8080 as normal, and I expected it to display the output. However, it displayed an error in transcription and gave the error message below.
Received file: uploads/input.wav
Error during transcription: APIConnectionError: Connection error.
at OpenAI.makeRequest (/Users/vivannkhanna/voice-recorder-app/node_modules/openai/core.js:304:19)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async /Users/vivannkhanna/voice-recorder-app/server.js:42:37 {
status: undefined,
headers: undefined,
request_id: undefined,
error: undefined,
code: undefined,
param: undefined,
type: undefined,
cause: FetchError: request to https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
at ClientRequest.\<anonymous\> (/Users/vivannkhanna/voice-recorder-app/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1501:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:\_http_client:500:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:531:35)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
type: 'system',
errno: 'ECONNRESET',
code: 'ECONNRESET'


Have you tried changing your IP address VPN?
Doesn't the api require any kind of authentication method? like token? API_KEYs? or something?

Yes I am using my api key from the openai website and that part of the code works well, I know it is able to use the api key. I tried turning on a vpn and that actually gave me a different error, one that does not have ECONRESET but just saying that the request to the openai servers timed out. I'll put it here.

Received file: uploads/input.wav
Error during transcription: APIConnectionTimeoutError: Request timed out.
at OpenAI.makeRequest (/Users/vivannkhanna/voice-recorder-app/node_modules/openai/core.js:302:23)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async /Users/vivannkhanna/voice-recorder-app/server.js:42:37 {
status: undefined,
headers: undefined,
request_id: undefined,
error: undefined,
code: undefined,
param: undefined,
type: undefined
}

provide a minimal reproductivecode https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Have you found a solution?
